# How to restrict editing privileges in excel per user

Tags: excel

How can I restrict editing privileges per user in a **shared** excel workbook that allows simultaneous using? For example, how can I share a spreadsheet with a user, but only allow the user to edit Column A?

Comment: You can password protect a workbook and open only some cells to edit - however this is not secure and a committed user can break the password.

Comment: here is the answer in this link:
[Lock or unlock specific areas of a protected worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-or-unlock-specific-areas-of-a-protected-worksheet-bdb8252f-d605-45cb-9712-137925867ad4)

Answer (score 1):

You select those cells which you want to have unprotected and right click.

Then select Format Cells

Then select the Protection Tab and uncheck the Locked checkbox.

Click Ok

Then Go to the Top and click on the Review Ribbon

Click Protect Sheet

Enter a password twice

Now only the person with the password can unlock and edit the sheet. The only cells another person can edit are those you 'Unprotected' earlier. The default is for all cells to be unchangeable once the sheet is protected.

However excel doesn't have very good protection and it can be cracked. It does stop most users from editing your protected items though.